# Laravel api guard - Does not save log or authenticates when second route parameter is a function

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am using the Api guard laravel (https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard) but just works when route its like this example below

```
Route::get('api/v1/books/{id}', 'BooksController@show');
```

if a i need to use a route like that

```
Route::get('api/v1/books/{id}', function(){

  App::make('App\Http\Controllers\Book\BookController')->getIndex();

});
```

The Api Guard don´t save the log or authenticates.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This library works when calling the controller because, [per the instructions](https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard#usage), your controller extends the `ApiGuardController` controller, and your closure obviously does not.

Luckily, it is also implemented as a route middleware, so you can also do something like this:

```
Route::get('api/v1/books/{id}', function() {

    App::make('App\Http\Controllers\Book\BookController')->getIndex();

})->middleware('apiguard');
```